# How to reset jquery Dropzone?

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

I would like to know is there a way to reset Dropzone. I am trying to set some different dropzone url if certain condition is true. Refer code below:

```
$("#regular").dropzone({ url: "someurl.html" });
if(true){
    $("#regular").dropzone({ url: "newurl.html" });
}
```

Above code gives me an error "Dropzone already attached."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myDPZone = new Dropzone("#regular", { url: "someurl.html" });
if(true){
    Dropzone.options.myDPZone  = {
     url: "newurl.html" 
    });
}
```